# why the result of Virtual_Guest.getBillingCycleBandwidthUsage result is not the same as shown in softlayer page

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to use Softlayer API to retrieve device bandwidth usage, per the Softlayer API https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest  i think the function getBillingCycleBandwidthUsage or getCurrentBandwidthSummary shoule works.
But after i executed such function , i found the return result is not same to what i saw on the "bandwitdth summary" page of control.softlayer.com.  So can anyone help to have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve same values than control portal page you need to use the service [SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getSummaryData](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_metric_tracking_object/getsummarydata).

The https://control.softlayer.com/network/bandwidth/summary and the **Bandwidth** tab in the Virtual Guest details pages call to that service.

## **First**

Retrieve the **metricTrackingObject.id** value, you can use following methods:

Use the method **SoftLayer_Account::getVirtualGuests** with a mask to get the **metricTrackingObject.id** of all virtual guests

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,metricTrackingObject.id]
```

For an specific device use the method **SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getObject** as following:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[guestID]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,metricTrackingObject.id]
```

In both cases the response is something like this:

```
{
    "fullyQualifiedDomainName": "guest01.example.com",
    "id": 111111111,
    "metricTrackingObject": {
        "id": 25815935
    }
}
```

Or you can also use the method **SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getMetricTrackingObjectId**

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[guestID]/getMetricTrackingObjectId
```

On my case the metricTrackingObject.id is **25815935**, this value is used in the bottom example (third step).

## **Second**

You need to know the date range of your billing cycle. Check the **anniversaryDayOfMonth** value when calling to the **SoftLayer_Account::getBillingInfo** method

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBillingInfo
```

In my case the **anniversaryDayOfMonth** is 4, so it means that my billing cycle is from 4th to the 3rd day of next month, this range is for all months.

## **Third**

Finally calls to **SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getSummaryData** as following:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/25815935/getSummaryData

Method: POST

{
    "parameters": [
        "2017-12-04T00:00:00-0600",
        "2018-01-03T23:59:59-0600",
        [
            {
                "keyName": "PUBLICIN",
                "name": "PUBLICin",
                "summaryType": "sum"
            },
            {
                "keyName": "PUBLICOUT",
                "name": "PUBLICout",
                "summaryType": "sum"
            }           
        ],
        43200
    ]
}
```

As you can see above, the date range is from to 4th to the 3rd day of next month, the parameters into array are the validTypes values you are trying to retrieve, and the value 43200 is the summaryPeriod, see  [SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getSummaryData](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_metric_tracking_object/getsummarydata)

The response is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "counter": 32195987,
        "dateTime": "2017-12-04T08:00:00-04:00",
        "type": "publicIn_net_octet"
    },
    {
        "counter": 3908213,
        "dateTime": "2017-12-04T08:00:00-04:00",
        "type": "publicOut_net_octet"
    },
    {
        "counter": 43489761,
        "dateTime": "2017-12-04T20:00:00-04:00",
        "type": "publicIn_net_octet"
    },
    {
        "counter": 14373554,
        "dateTime": "2017-12-04T20:00:00-04:00",
        "type": "publicOut_net_octet"
    },
]
```

Through a language programming, you must to sum the **counter** values of all **publicIn_net_octet** to get the **bandwidth IN** and the **counter** of **publicOut_net_octet** to get the **bandwidth OUT**

On my case the **bandwidth IN** was 66158912635 bytes, using [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes) to convert it to GB the values is 66.158912635 GB.

Rounding it should be 66.16 GB which is the same value than image below.

[image]

To get the **Total** you need to sum the IN and OUT values.